# Who gives us transition level when it varies?

Tags: air-traffic-control, weather, atis

Who gives us transition level when it varies?

ATC, ATIS, any others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the country's AIP, ENR section.

ATIS, ATC or FIS is a good bet otherwise but it remains a bet.

In some EASA countries, you can calculate it yourself if the Transition altitude is fixed. E.g. Germany's TA is 5000ft, with the transition layer a minimum of 1000 ft. So with a QNH of 1014 the TL will be FL60, 978-1013 it'll be FL70 and 977- will be FL80. Others are different but they don't hide the information, it's in the AIP.

Comment: What do you mean by ENR section? Ok great mate,  so you bet as in you are sure? So ATIS,ATC and FIS...Isn't transition altitude always fixed or known so to say...so you can always find transition level...but I know that some countires have a transition layer big enough like 2000 ft thay they fix the  transorion level....

Comment: I'm not a betting man, I like to be sure so I read the AIP of the country I fly over or through. Every AIP has a number of sections, e.g. AD for the Aerodrome info and ENR for enroute. Here's e.g. Belgium's Transition Altitude and Level:
https://ops.skeyes.be/html/belgocontrol_static/eaip/eAIP_Main/html/eAIP/EB-ENR-1.7-en-GB.html
Or here's how the UK works: https://nats-uk.ead-it.com/cms-nats/opencms/en/Publications/AIP/Current-AIRAC/html/eAIP/EG-ENR-1.7-en-GB.html

Comment: Great mate, very kind.Amazing✈✈❣❣

Comment: @YosefJabbour Glad it helped. Please accept an answer to mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Usually ATIS, or the atc which first clears you to an altitude if there is no ATIS. In some cases (e.g US) it is fixed so there is no need for it to be given. In those cases its usually charted in the arrival/approach chart.

Comment: What is the transition level in the us? Also why is it fixed? Isn't the value of transition level dependent on qnh = local pressure conditions...( some countries fix the tranaition level if the transition layer distance is large...)

Comment: So is the Transition Level in the US fixed to FL200? What happens if the QNG drops below 977? The vertical separation between aircraft cruising at 18.000ft and at FL200 would be only 970ft or even less with lower air pressure?

Comment: @pcfreakxx In the US, the lowest usable flight level is FL180, FL190 or FL200 depending on QNH to ensure 1000 ft separation with 17,000 ft ([SKYbrary](https://skybrary.aero/articles/transition-altitudelevel)).

Comment: @Bianfable Thanks for your explanation! I was falsely assuming the TA was 18.000ft in the US. But having a TA of 17.000ft and variable TRL of FL180-FL200 makes perfectly sense. It’s the same here in Germany, although with different values (TA 5.000ft, TRL: FL60-80).

Comment: @pcfreakxx Technically TA is at 18,000 ft in the US. It's just not the highest usable altitude (unlike in Europe).

Comment: @Bianfable That doesn’t make sense to me. Does that mean you are using completely contrary definitions of TA and TRL than the rest of the world? Per ICAO definition the local QNH shall be used at or below TA and TRL is the lowest usable FL.

Comment: @pcfreakxx Did you read the [SKYbrary](https://skybrary.aero/articles/transition-altitudelevel) article I linked? It explains the differences between North America and Europe quite nicely.

Comment: @Bianfable I just read it, thank you so much! I have to admit: this seems really counterintuitive, lucky I don’t have to remember.